# Как правильно подменять объекты внутри метода класса для тестирования?

Tags: юнит-тесты

Пытаюсь применить модульное тестирование, не понимаю как подменить объект Foo в этом случае:

```
class Foo {
    bool DoSomething() { return true; }
};

class Bar {
    bool Process() {
        Foo * foo = new Foo();
        return foo->DoSomething();
        delete foo;
    }

};
```

Пытаюсь тестировать с помощью google tests следующим кодом:

```
TEST(Bar, Process_true) {
    Bar bar;

    bool result = bar.Process();

    EXPECT_EQ(true, result);
}
```

Как в методе Process правильно подменить объект foo?

Comment: ваши обьекты и функции_члены асолютно ничего не делают, кроме того, что  Bar ::Process  пораждает утечку памяти., так что возникает вопрос:  зачем вообше создавать и зачем подменить обьект, если результат будет тот же?...

Comment: Как вариант, то можно попробовать определить обертки для операторов `new` и `delete` и использовать их для точки модификации. Сейчас вы никак не можете повлиять на исполняемый код.

Comment: Можно вынести `Foo` в качестве параметра шаблона и для теста использовать другой параметр. @MrBin от подмены операторов создание экземпляра класса `Foo` никак не изменится.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, я привел минимальный код в качестве примера, на всякий случай удаление объекта добавил. Но вопрос все же по модульному тестированию, а не по общим практикам написания программ.

Comment: @VTT, прошу уточнить: шаблона метода? Но ведь тогда я раскрываю внутреннюю реализацию класса и в рабочем коде, чего не хотелось бы.
Также мне не хотелось бы добавлять его через конструктор или метод. Я думал задействовать фабрику создающую объект, но тогда в конструкторе нужно передавать саму фабрику? Или заводить общую фабрику на весь проект, как синглтон или получать ее от сервис-локатора. Но тогда получается куча фабрик.

Comment: В данном примере никак не подменить, потому что Foo создаётся внутри метода. Нужно сделать инъекцию: метод (или конструктор класса) должен принимать параметр Foo. Тогда вместо реального объекта можно передать мок.

Comment: Вам стоит определиться, хотите вы иметь возможность подменять `Foo` или нет. Делая это через параметр шаблоны вы производите подмену во время компиляции, избегая тем самым оверхеда при работе.

Comment: @VTT, нее. Чуть более глубокое декорирование чем просто другой оператор. Через внешнюю шаблонную функцию, а там уже есть куча вариантов.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за помощь, сам задал вопрос - сам и отвечу.

Самый подходящий вариант для подмены внутреннего объекта - это применение паттерна "шаблонный метод".

Нужно:

1. Создание самого объекта вынести в отдельный приватный метод класса.
2. Сделать этот метод класса виртуальным.
3. Унаследовать от рабочего класса новый и переопределить в нем как нам нужно этот виртуальный метод, возвращая вместо оригинального экземпляра класса, его замоканный вариант.
4. Протестировать метод класса, УНАСЛЕДОВАВШЕГО рабочий класс, его функциональность будет аналогично оригинальному классу.

Плюсы: после внедрения через конструктор, свойства и методы самый простой способ внедрения. Фабрики, сервис локаторы и composition root уже сложнее. Подходит даже для классов без интерфейсов.

Код примера из вопроса меняется на следующий:

```
class Foo {
public:
    bool DoSomething() { return true; }
};

class Bar {
public:
    bool Process() {
        Foo * foo = CreateFoo();
        return foo->DoSomething();
        delete foo;
    }
private:
    virtual Foo * CreateFoo() { return new Foo; };

};

class Bar2 : public Bar {
private:
    Foo * CreateFoo() override { return Mock<Foo>.get(); };

};

TEST(Bar2, Process_true) {
    Bar2 bar;

    bool result = bar.Process();

    EXPECT_EQ(true, result);
}
```